# Monotonicity, Convexity, and Smoothness of the KL-Divergence between Two Brownian Motions with Different Initializers

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, it.information-theory, optimal-transportation

We consider the two distributions
$$
p_t = p_0 * N(0, tI),\quad q_t  = q_0 * N(0, t I),
$$
where $*$ denotes the convolution between two densities, while $p_0$ and $q_0$ have the same mean and variance. In particular, we assume that $q_0$ is $N(0, I)$. In other words, we consider two random variables
$$
X_t = X_0 + N(0, t I)\sim p_t, \quad Y_t = Y_0 + N(0, tI)\sim q_t,
$$
where $X_0\sim p_0$ and $Y_0\sim q_0 = N(0, I)$.

We are interested in characterizing the evolution of 
$$
\text{KL}(p_t, q_t) = \int p_t \log \left(\frac{p_t}{q_t}\right) dx
$$
along $t$. In particular, we aim to prove:

(i) $\text{KL}(p_t, q_t)$ is monotonically decreasing along $t$;

(ii) $\text{KL}(p_t, q_t)$ is convex along t;

(iii) $\text{KL}(p_t, q_t)$ is smooth along t, that is, 
$\frac{d^2\text{KL}(p_t, q_t)}{dt^2}
$ is upper bounded.

(Comment: As pointed out by Jon, (i) follows directly from the data processing inequality. As pointed out by Nawaf, (ii) also holds.)

Comment: Point (i) follows from the data processing inequality.

Comment: @Jon You are absolutely right. Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Comment: Seems better to pose the new part (iii) as a new question, because it was added to the body and the title of the question after the OP received an answer; see, e.g., the nice discussion in https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3057/splitting-a-question

Comment: Minkov, I agree with Nawaf: he took the time to answer your question, and to change the question so as to render his answer now obsolete (or out-of-date as you put it) is not good form. I recommend that you accept his answer, and ask your part (iii) as a new question, with a bounty if you like.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee You are absolutely right. I will take your answer and open a new question. Thanks again for your insightful answer!

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee The bounty will be transferred to you in 8 hours. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the KL divergence in terms of the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of the random variables $X_t$ and $Y_t$; the result quickly follows.  Indeed, since $Y_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1+t)$, we have \begin{align*}
\operatorname{KL}(p_t, q_t) &= - h(p_t) + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{x^2}{1+t} p_t(x) dx + \frac{1}{2} \log(1+t) + \frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi) \\
&= - h(p_t) + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}((X_0+\sqrt{t} \mathcal{N}(0,1))^2)\frac{1}{1+t}  + \frac{1}{2} \log(1+t) + \frac{1}{2} \log(2 \pi) \\
&= -h(p_t) + h(q_t)
\end{align*} where $h(\cdot)$ is the differential entropy.  By Lemma 2 of [Zhang, Anantharam and Geng](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/20/3/182/htm), subject to $\operatorname{var}(X_0)=1$, the minimum of $-\frac{d^2}{dt^2} h(p_t)$ is achieved when $X_0$ is Gaussian.  Thus, $-\frac{d^2}{dt^2} h(p_t) \ge -\frac{d^2}{dt^2} h(q_t)$, and hence, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\operatorname{KL}(p_t, q_t) \ge 0$ which implies that $\operatorname{KL}(p_t, q_t)$ is convex with respect to $t$.

**ADD**

The Gaussian minimality result used above seems to go back to

McKean, H. P., [**Speed of approach to equilibrium for Kac’s caricature of a Maxwellian gas**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00264463), Arch. Ration. Mech. Anal. 21, 343-367 (1966). [ZBL1302.60049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1302.60049).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the revision, Nawaf!

Comment: In fact, is it possible to prove that the second-order derivative is also upper bounded?

Comment: @Minkov The answer to the new part (iii) of this question seems to boil down to obtaining a bound on the second derivative of the differential entropy of $X_t$. A formula for this quantity -- attributed to H. McKean, G. Toscani, and C. Villani -- is given in (4) of https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/20/3/182/htm#B7-entropy-20-00182. This formula involves an expected value over $X_t$, and in order to bound, seems to require additional assumptions on $X_0$.

Comment: I see. What kind of assumption is needed for this? One possible thing I have in mind is the lower boundedness of the density of $X_0$, which seems a bit strong.

Comment: @Minkov Agree that seems a bit strong; conjecture that the right assumptions are those that naturally come from expanding the expected value of McKean, Toscani and Villani in terms of the density of $X_0$, and then precisely estimating the terms.